# generate Primefaces MenuModel from database

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, recursion, primefaces

i want to ask how to make generate menumodel from database using recursive function.
i already make this class but it's not working. please help me,i already find and trying for a week .thanks

```
public class MenuDAOImpl extends ManagerBase<MenuMaster> implements MenuDAO {

    private List<MenuMaster> list;
    private List<MenuData> datas;

    @Override
    public MenuModel getMenu() {
        MenuModel model = new DefaultMenuModel();
        String[] orders = new String[]{"id"};
        try {
            list = getBySQLQuery("PARENT_MENU_ID=0", orders, 1000);
            for (MenuMaster menuMaster : list) {
                menuChild(menuMaster);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return model;
        // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private List<MenuData> menuChild(MenuMaster master) {
        List<MenuData> listChild = new ArrayList<MenuData>();
        String[] orders = new String[]{"id"};
        try {
            MenuData data = new MenuData();
            data.mm = master;
            data.mms = getBySQLQuery("PARENT_MENU_ID=" + master.getParentMenuId(), orders, 1000);
            listChild.add(data);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return listChild;
    }

    public class MenuData {

        private MenuMaster mm;
        private List<MenuMaster> mms;

        public MenuData() {
        }

        public MenuMaster getMm() {
            return mm;
        }

        public void setMm(MenuMaster mm) {
            this.mm = mm;
        }

        public List<MenuMaster> getMms() {
            return mms;
        }

        public void setMms(List<MenuMaster> mms) {
            this.mms = mms;
        }
    }
}
```

this is my database table (sorry i can't upload images)

ID  |  MENU_NAME    |  DISPLAY_NAME   |   URL                  |PARENT_MENU_ID   |
1   |   employee    |   Employee      | /employee.xhtml        |  0          |
2   |   employeemenu|   Employee      | /employee.xhtml        |  1          |
 
3   |   utils       |   Utility       |                        |  0          |
 
7   |   asdf        |   asdf          |                        |  6          |
 
6   |   utilsmenu   |   test          |                        |  3          |
 
5   |   utilsdata   |   Admin Config  | asdf                   |  3          |
 
4   |   menu        |   Menu Editor   | /utility/menu.xhtml    |  3          |

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I had lying around, I create the menumodel by appending submenus and menuitems to his getChildren() property

```
private MenuModel model;

public MenuModel getModel() {

    if(model != null) return model;

    model = new DefaultMenuModel();
    addDynamicMenus();

    return model;
}

private void addDynamicMenus(){

    if(modules == null){
        modules = service.getModulesByUserLogin(loginBean.getUsername());
    }

    Submenu currfather = null;

    for(SpFeModuleForUser s : modules){

        if(currfather == null || (!currfather.getId().equals("menu_" + s.getModuleID()))){
            currfather = new Submenu();
              currfather.setLabel(Modules.getSingleton().getString(s.getModuleName()));
            currfather.setId("menu_"+s.getModuleID());
            model.addSubmenu(currfather);
        }

        MenuItem mi = new MenuItem();

        mi.setValue(Modules.getSingleton().getString(s.getNAME()));
        mi.setId("_" + s.getKey());
        mi.setTarget("_self");
        mi.setTitle(Modules.getSingleton().getString(s.getNAME() + "_Description"));
        mi.setAjax(false);
        mi.setUrl(url);
        // Add parameters
        UIParameter param = new UIParameter();
        param.setName("moduleid");
        param.setValue(s.getKey());
        mi.getChildren().add(param);

        mi.setProcess("@all");
        currfather.getChildren().add(mi);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me SpFeModuleForUser class?i'm litle confuse,how many menu level i can generate?thanks

Comment: well that's just my model class, I have two levels, SubMenu and MenuItems